# Why we need to put a lot of efforts in just to achieve cross browser compatibility?

Tags: javascript, html, css, cross-browser, cross-platform

I have a strange observation that in any web application designing, why we need to put a huge amount of efforts just to make them work in all the browsers. I mean probably the efforts to development or designing the things are sometimes equal to just test and make it work in every browser.Even we have well stated standards define which are accepted globally (may be W3C standards ? I am not sure).

Please don't miss understand the question as I know that we can definitely reduce these efforts to a certain level but still a considerable bunch is always needed to work with.

So why all the browsers or kind of softwares are not following the set of standards ? I am taking JavaScripts(i.e events, properties, syntax etc) CSS and HTML also into consideration.

Please help if you know the way and correct me if I am wrong...

Comment: may have know the reason why Close votes ??

Comment: Because W3C actually doesnt write "standards" but recommandations. And different companies editing different browsers have different interests. It is up to the browser editors to follow these standards, or not. We could have had a more powerfull and easy to developp on web plateform , but MS said no, for instance ( back in 2006 i think , with the ECMAScript 4 fiasco ).
ES4 would have brought choice , to go on with the messy Js we now know or get a better structured langage for heavy client apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A long time ago, there were basically just two browsers: Internet Explorer and Netscape. Microsoft did not like Netscape and had a huge market share so they added whatever they wanted/considered useful without caring about it being standardized or not - and netscape did not add every non-standard Microsoft feature, too. So IE contains lots of proprietary stuff that is not standardized.

Besides that, IE6 was not actively maintaned (besides security fixes) for a very long time. All bugs present there were never fixed - and even in IE7 there are some bugs that require hacks or at least additional efforts to make things look like in other browsers.

Comment: OK I got your point.But what about the international standards defined and even accepted globally ?

Comment: Microsoft simply did not care about them. They are not laws after all. It resulted in a small amount of nice things, too: AJAX, more specifically the `XmlHttpRequest` object, was one of those non-standard microsoft things, too, until it got widely adapted by other browser vendors.

Answer (score 1):

There are several reasons why one browser may not support same standards:

- To exert monopoly.
- To add new features, which other browsers are lacking, and which standards have failed to cover.
- Not maintained anymore.